# setInterval function looping too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have similar code to what is below and the setInterval is running a lot faster than 1000ms and it crashes/ slows down the page.

```
var checkDiffTest = function(){

    console.log('test checkDiff init');

    var interval = setInterval(countdownTest(), 1000);

}
var countdownTest = function(){

    console.log('test countdown init');

    checkDiffTest();

}

countdownTest();
```

Comment: `setInterval` wants a function reference: `setInterval(countdownTest, 1000)`. `countdownTest()` just calls `countdownTest` immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting a new interval each time the interval runs:

- Your interval calls `countdownTest()`
- Which called `checkDiffTest()`
- Which creates a new interval (while the last one is still running)

A new 1000ms interval is started every 1000ms.

---

It looks as though you want `setTimeout()` instead.

Also `countdownTest()` as `setInterval`'s first parameter invokes that function straight away. You want to pass the function as reference:

```
var checkDiffTest = function(){
    console.log('test checkDiff init')
    var interval = setTimeout(countdownTest, 1000);

}
var countdownTest = function(){
    console.log('test countdown init');
    checkDiffTest();
}

countdownTest();
```